# Ray: Loop through list with additional arguments across cluster

Tags: python, ray

I have a function that loops through a list:

```
for id_ in id_list:
    scrape(id_, str(id_.split('/')[-1]), id_list.index(id_), len(id_list), target_path)
```

I can run it in parallel using:

```
for id_ in id_list:
        p1 = Process(target=scrape, args=(id_, str(id_.split('/')[-1]), id_list.index(id_), len(id_list), target_path))
        p1.start()
```

However, I would like to use Ray and parallelise it across a cluster. Seem to be having trouble in getting it to loop through the list in Ray - how do I do that?

Comment: maybe first create list with all values and later use `RAY` with this list. I would do this at least for `multiprocesing.Pool()` which needs all values at start

Comment: if you have problem with `ray` then you should show `ray` code and full error message

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `Ray` and I don't know what is your problem because you didn't show `Ray` code and full error message but if I would have to use `multiprocessing.Pool()` to parallelize then I would have to first use `for`-loop to create list with all arguments

```
all_args = []

for id_ in id_list:
     all_args.append( (id_, str(id_.split('/')[-1]), id_list.index(id_), len(id_list), target_path))
```

And later run it without `for`-loop

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
p.starmap(target=scrape, args=all_args)
```

---

Eventually I would have to use list comprehension to do it in one line

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
p.starmap(target=scrape, args=((id_, str(id_.split('/')[-1]), id_list.index(id_) for id_ in id_lis))
```

---

I expect that `Ray` may need the same method.

---

**EDIT:**

Example code with `Ray`

```
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def scrape(id_, text, index_, length, path):
    return 'id: {} | text: {} | index: {} | len: {} | path: {}'.format(id_, text, index_, length, path)

id_list = ['2020/1', '2020/2', '2020/3', '2020/4']
target_path = '/home/user'

all_args = []

for id_ in id_list:
     all_args.append( (id_, str(id_.split('/')[-1]), id_list.index(id_), len(id_list), target_path))

futures = [scrape.remote(*args) for args in all_args]
all_results = ray.get(futures)

print(all_results)
```

Simpler

```
futures = []

for id_ in id_list:
    futures.append(scrape.remote(id_, str(id_.split('/')[-1]), id_list.index(id_), len(id_list), target_path))

all_results = ray.get(futures)
```